# SMS sent with AT Command has random sender number

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I've got a SIM7600G-H version 2. I want to use it to send and receive SMSes and phone calls through my PC. I've got it connected with a USB cable and I'm writing Kotlin code to communicate with [jssc](https://github.com/java-native/jssc/).

It's important to know...

- I have a UK SIM card (the provider is Giffgaff)
- I'm in the Netherlands, so I'm roaming.

###### SMS

I can use AT Commands to successfully send SMS messages...

```sh
> AT+CMGS="+31600..."
> test message \u001a
+CMGS: 55
```

But when I receive them, the sender number is completely random, and from different countries.

[image: screenshot of SMS app with multiple test messages that I've sent from my SIM6700, all from different sender numbers]

I don't recognise any of the numbers. I don't know where they come from.

###### Phone calls

I'm also unable to make phone calls.

```sh
> ATD+31600....
NO CARRIER
```

### Questions

1. How can I make sure that when I send SMSes with my SIM7600 that they appear as the correct number?
2. How can I configure the SIM7600 to make phone calls?

---

#### Diagnostics

The 'net light pin' LED usually flashes 200ms on, 200ms (4G registered), which seems fine.

`AT+CEER` usually returns `+CEER: No cause information available`, and sometimes returns `bearer capability not authorized`

`AT+CUSD=1 -> OK` and `ATD*#5005*7672#` takes about 30 seconds to always reports `NO CARRIER`

##### Device details

```sh
> ATI
Manufacturer: SIMCOM INCORPORATED
Model: SIMCOM_SIM7600G-H
Revision: SIM7600M22_V2.0
IMEI: 812[omitted]
+GCAP: +CGSM
```

##### Network info

The network settings seem okay. Correct carrier name and details, decent signal quality, roaming, LTE.

```sh
> AT+CSPN?
+CSPN   : "giffgaff",1
> AT+COPS?
+COPS   : 0,0,"NL KPN giffgaff",7
> AT+CSQ
+CSQ    : 25,99
> AT+CREG?
+CEREG  : 0,5
> AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: 0,4
> AT+CNSMOD?
+CNSMOD : 0,8
+CIMI   : 123...[omitted] # looks okay 
+CPSI   : LTE,Online,204-08,0xF03D,4098848,203,EUTRAN-BAND3,1300,5,5,-88,-946,-658,12
```

#### PDP / APN

I've tried setting the APN to [Giffgaff settings](https://www.giffgaff.com/help/articles/internet-apn-settings-guide), and I think they're set correctly, using.

- APN:                  `giffgaff.com`
- Username:             `gg`
- Password:             `p`
- Proxy:                `{Leave Blank}`
- MCC:                  `234`
- MNC:                  `10`
- APN protocol:         `IPv4v6`
- APN roaming protocol: `IPv4`
- Authentication type:  `PAP`

```sh
+CGDCONT  : 1,"IPV4V6","giffgaff.com","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
+CGDCONT  : 2,"IP","giffgaff.com","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0
+CGDSCONT : # (no output)
+CGACT    : 1,0
+CGACT    : 2,1
```

The SMS Service Center number seems [correct](https://www.giffgaff.com/help/articles/how-to-perform-a-manual-roam)

```sh
+CSCA: "+447802002606",145
```

#### AT&V - Display current configuration

```sh
> AT&V
&C: 2; &D: 2; &E: 1; &F: 0; &S: 0; &W: 0; E: 1; L: 0; M: 0; Q: 0; V: 1;
X: 1; Z: 0; \Q: 3; \S: 0; \V: 0; O: 0; S0: 0; S2: 43; S3: 13; S4: 10;
S5: 8; S6: 2; S7: 0; S8: 2; S9: 6; S10: 14; S11: 95; S30: 0; S103: 1;
S104: 1; +FCLASS: 0; +ICF: 3,3; +IFC: 0,0; +IPR: 115200; +DR: 0;
+DS: 0,0,2048,6; +CMEE: 2; +WS46: 25; +CFUN:; +IPREX: 115200;
+CBST: 0,0,1; +CRLP: (61,61,48,6,0),(61,61,48,6,1),(240,240,52,6,2);
+CV120: 1,1,1,0,0,0; +CHSN: 0,0,0,0; +CSSN: 0,0; +CREG: 0; +CGREG: 0;
+CEREG: 0; +CSCS: "IRA"; +CSTA: 129;  +CR: 0; +CRC: 0;
+CGDCONT: (1,"IPV4V6","giffgaff.com","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0),(2,"IP","giffgaff.com","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0);
+CGDSCONT: ; +CGTFT: ; +CGEQREQ: ; +CGEQMIN: ; +CGEQOS: ; +CGQREQ: ;
+CGQMIN: ; +CGEREP: 0,0; +CGDATA: "PPP"; +CGCLASS: "A"; +CGPIAF: 0,0,0,0;
+CGSMS: 2; +CSMS: 0; +CMGF: 1; +CSAS: 0; +CRES: 0; +CSCA: "",;
+CSMP: ,,0,0; +CSDH: 0; +CSCB: 0,"",""; +CMGP: 4098,0,,0,; +ES: ,,;
+ESA: 0,,,,0,0,255,; +CMOD: 0; +CEMODE: 1; +CVHU: 1; ; ; ; ; ; ;
+CSCLK: 0; +CCUART: 0; +CFGRI: 0,60,120;  +CUARTSD: 500; +CURCD: 0;
+CUARTLOG: 0; +CUARTRM: 0; +CFGRIDTM: 60,120; +CATR: 0; +CNMP: 2;
+CNRP: 255; +CNAOP: 0; +CNSDP: 2; +CNSMOD: 0; +CNLSA: 0; +CEXTEPLMN: 1;
+CSQFMT: 1; +AUTOCSQ: 0,0; +CSQDELTA: 5; +CPSI: 0; +CMGSI: 2;
+CMGRMI: 4,0; +MONI: 0; +CRUPSI: 0; +CRUSET: 0; +CGPS: 0,1; +CGPSMSB: 1;
+CGPSINFO: 0; +CGPSINFOCFG: 0,0,0; +CGPSHOR: 50; +CGPSPMD: 65407;
+CGPSXD: 0; +CGNSSINFO: 0; +CSOCKAUTH: 1,0,""; +CGAUTH: 1,0,""; ;
+CIPHEAD: 1; +CIPSRIP: 1; +CIPCCFG: 10,0,0,1,0,0,500; +CIPENSRXGET: 0;
+CIPMODE: 0;  +CPIN: ��������,��������; +CMEC: 0,0,0,0;
+CIND: 0,4,1,1,1,0,1,0; +CMER: 0,0,0,0,0; +CGATT: 1; +CGACT(1,0),(2,1);
+CPBS: "SM"; +CPMS: "SM","SM","SM"; +CNMI: 2,1,0,0,0; +CMMS: 0;
+CCUG: 0,0,0; +COPS: 0,0,""; +CUSD: 1; +CAOC: 1; +CCWA: 0;
+CPOL: 0,2,"",0,0,0,0; +CPLS: 0; +CTZR: 0; +CTZU: 0; +CLIP: 0; +COLP: 0;
+CDIP: 0; +CLIR: 0; +CSDF: 1; +CEN: 0; +CPSMS: 0,"","","","";
+CEDRXS: 0,1,""; +CCARDMA: 0; +STK: 0; +CSALPHA: 0; +MORING: 0;
+CWAKEUPSMSSWITCH: 0; +CFILTERSMSSWITCH: 0; +EB: 1,0,30; +EFCS: 1;
+ER: 0;  +ESR: 1; +ETBM: 1,1,20; +MA: ; +MR: 0; +MS: ; +MV18R: 0;
+MV18S: 0,0,0; +CXT: 0; +CDR: 0; +CDS: 0,1,2048,6; +CFC: 0; +CFG: "";
+CQD: 10; +CCRC: 0; +QCMUX: C,2; +CTA: 0; +ILRR: 0; +QCPIN: ,; *CNTI: 0;
^PREFMODE: 0; ^DSCI: 0; ^MODE: 0; ^CPIN: ,

OK
```

---

### Update 1

```sh
# try finding own number
> AT+CNUM?
ERROR
# check the command does exist
> AT+CNUM=?
OK
# current phonebook
> AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "SM",4,100
# show possible phonebooks
> AT+CPBS=?
+CPBS: ("SM","DC","FD","LD","MC","ME","RC","EN","ON")
# switch to ON (MSISDN list)
> AT+CPBS=ON
ERROR
# ON needs to be in quotes
> AT+CPBS="ON"
OK
# find by text (if null, will list all entries)
# none available
> AT+CPBF=
ERROR
# show valid indexes
> AT+CPBR=?
+CPBR: (1-3),40,14
# can't find any numbers
> AT+CPBR=1,3
+CME ERROR: not found
# store my number
> AT+CPBW=,"+4470..."
OK
# 
> AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "ON",1,3
# fetch first index
> AT+CPBR=1
+CPBR: 1,"+4470...",145,""
# find by text now returns my number
> AT+CPBF=
+CPBF: 1,"+4470...",145,""
# my number is now correctly returned
> AT+CNUM
+CPBR: 1,"+4470...",145,""
```

All looks good, but it still doesn't work.

The status light shows that it is reconnecting, and then settles into a 200ms/200ms on/off cycle.

```sh
> AT+CMGS="+3160..."
> asd \u001a
```

The status light then turns solid red (searching for network).

Eventually (~ 2 minutes later) it returns

```sh
+CMS ERROR: Unknown error
> AT+CEER
+CEER: EMM attach failed
```

###### Status info

```sh
> ATD*#5005*7672#
NO CARRIER # takes around 30 seconds to return
> AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"NL KPN giffgaff",0
> AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 19,99
> AT+CREG?
+CREG: 2,5,1806,AC07E0
> AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: 0,4
> AT+CNSMOD?
+CNSMOD : 0,7
> AT+CPSI?
+CPSI: WCDMA,Online,204-08,0x1806,11274208,WCDMA 900,233,3011,0,4.0,76,20,38,500
> AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,0
+CGACT: 2,0
# activate 2nd PDP (it's Giffgaff's roaming one)
> AT+CGACT=1,2
OK
> AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,0
+CGACT: 2,1
> AT+CREG?
+CREG: 5,1806,AC07E0
```

Answer (score 1):

As per location

> - I have a UK SIM card (the provider is Giffgaff)
> - I'm in the    Netherlands, so I'm roaming.

this looks like a behavior of the roaming arrangement Giffgaff  has with the local provider.

however if your modem supports AT+CNUM then it should return returns the MSISDNs related to the subscriber

here is a example from [https://iot-developer.thalesgroup.com](https://iot-developer.thalesgroup.com/tutorial/how-use-atcnum-query-own-number) :

```
at+cnum?

+CME ERROR: unknown     // response

at+cpbs?                                   - display the active phonebook storage

+CPBS: "SM",250,250    // response

OK 

at+cpbs=ON           - select the active phonebook storage to MSISDN list

OK

at+cpbs?                                 -  display the active phonebook storage,

+CPBS: "ON",0,3                    - MSISDN list is empty

OK

at+cpbw=,"+48723976327"    - enter your own MSISDN

OK

at+cpbs?                                  -  display the active phonebook storage,

+CPBS: "ON",1,3                    - MSISDN list has one item

OK

at+cpbr=1                                 - reading MSISDN list, position 1

+CPBR: 1,"+48723976327",145,""  - own MSISDN

OK

at+cnum

+CNUM: ,"+48723976327",145      - own MSISDN
```

Comment: I've tried this (see the update in my question) and now when I try to send an SMS the SIM6700 doesn't send the SMS and disconnects from the network. Can you explain what these commands are supposed to do, and why?

Comment: AT+CNUM is the command to retrieve own number.  AT+CNUM command reads a special phone book storage area reserved for the SIM's own phone numbers. AT+CPBS="XX" selects the active phonebook storage, in you case formally  "SM" (SIM phonebook) was selected and now it set to "ON" (MSISDN list). and AT+CPBW writes phonebook entry in location number (eg : AT+CPBW=3,"88888888",129,"aSemy" , first parameter but if the index is not given,
the first free entry will be used ). in this case AT+CPBW=,"+4470..." was written MSISDN list as first entry.  AT+CREG status is 5 – that means registered, roaming.

Comment: Thanks - but why are they relevant to the problems I have? What are they supposed to do to resolve them, and why didn't they?

Comment: in most cases service provider who issues the  sim card stores your number on the sim,  but in your case it was empty, and service provider has not saved that number that means service provider uses least cost routing to send your sms while roaming. it just like using a calling cards, where receiver does not see the number you are calling but some random overseas number.  in this scenario if you reply to the sms you received immediately you might get the reply on  at the modem end,  but that is not guaranteed. ( the method that is being used by web based sms services. ),

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting! Since it's still not working, is there any more configuration I've set? I think I've gone through just about every AT Command in the SIM6700 manual and I'm still unable to send SMSs.

Comment: remove the number from ON" (MSISDN list) ;    Integer type values in the range of location numbers of phonebook memory.If <index> is not given,
the first free entry will be used. If <index> is given as the only parameter, the phonebook entry
specified by <index> is deleted.If record number <index> already exists, it will be overwritten. so you can  use AT+CPBS="ON" to switch to MSISDN list and then delete the entry you wrote. obviously the network doesn't like you setting the own phone number.  secondly you can put the sim on to mobile phone (if you have basic 2g phone) and send out a sms,